# Fullcalendar synchronization with Google Agenda

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to include a FullCalendar into a website, synchronized with Google Agenda. I call the function like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: { url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/laporte.julie%40gmail.com/public/basic" }
    });
});
```

The calendar is shown well, but not the data into it. My config in Google Agenda is good. Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you include: ?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
```

You can reference here : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/ for more info on the subject.